# How to prevent state updates from a function, running an async call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i have a bit of a weird problem i dont know how to solve.

In my code i have a custom hook with a bunch of functionality for a fetching a list
of train journeys. I have some useEffects to that keeps loading in new journeys untill the last journey of the day.

When i change route, while it is still loading in new journeys. I get the "changes to unmounted component" React error.
I understand that i get this error because the component is doing an async fetch that finishes after i've gone to a new page.

The problem i can't figure out is HOW do i prevent it from doing that? the "unmounted" error always occur on one of the 4 lines listed in the code snippet.

Mock of the code:

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [journeys, setJourneys] = useState([]);
  const [hasLaterDepartures, setHasLaterDepartures] = useState(true);

  const getJourneys = async (date, journeys) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setHasLaterDepartures(true);
    const selectedDateJourneys = await fetchJourney(date); // Fetch that returns 0-3 journeys
    if (condition1) setHasLaterDepartures(false); // trying to update unmounted component

    if (condition2) {
      if (condition3) {
        setJourneys(something1); // trying to update unmounted component
      } else {
        setJourneys(something2) // trying to update unmounted component
      }
    } else {
      setJourneys(something3); // trying to update unmounted component
    }
  };


  // useEffects for continous loading of journeys.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasLaterDepartures) setLoading(false);
  }, [hasLaterDepartures]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasLaterDepartures && journeys.length > 0) {
      const latestStart = ... // just a date
      if (latestStart.addMinutes(5).isSameDay(latestStart)) {
        getJourneys(latestStart.addMinutes(5), journeys);
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
  }, [journeys]);
```

I can't use a variable like isMounted = true in the useEffect beacuse it would reach inside the if statement and reach a "setState" by the time i'm on another page.

Moving the entire call into a useEffect doesn't seem to work either. I am at a loss.

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of `fetchJourney` too?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Unfortunately i can't, it shouldn't have anything to do with the problem its just a fetch. The problem is that by the time i'm on a new page the "getJourneys" function tried to update state.

Comment: I'm not sure it has nothing to do with it, as it's likely the function which is causing the component to unmount?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useEffect - Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524063/useeffect-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Comment: you should probably use useContext + Provider, or some kind of store with your hook, so it doesn't get reloaded everytime you go to a new route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable called `mounted` with `useRef`, initialised as `true`. Then add an effect to set `mounted.current` to `false` when the component unmounts.

You can use `mounted.current` anywhere inside the component to see if it's mounted, and check that before setting any state.

`useRef` gives you a variable you can mutate but which doesn't cause a rerender.

Comment: Like this?

  const isMounted = useRef(true);

  isMounted && setJourneys(something1);

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = false;
  }, []);


Because this doesn't work, i still get "unmounted" error

Comment: You need to use `isMounted.current` to access the latest value, otherwise you're referencing the ref object itself which will always be truthy

Answer (score 0):

When you use useEffect hook with action which can be done after component change you should also take care about clean effect when needed. Maybe example help you, also check this [page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

```
useEffect(() => {
    let isClosed = false
    
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await response.json()
        if ( !isClosed ) {
             setState( data )
        }
    };

    fetchData()

    return () => {
      isClosed = true
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I would have several setStates inside my "if (!isClosed)" block, and the code could jump in there just as i go to another page. And now the component is unmounted but it will still try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, you probably want to create a Store **that doesn't reload everytime you change route** (client side).

Example of a store using useContext();

```
const MyStoreContext = createContext()

export function useMyStore() {
    const context = useContext(MyStoreContext)
    if (!context && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        throw new Error(`useMyStore must be used within a MyStoreContext`)
    }
    return context
}

export function MyStoreProvider(props) {
    
    const [ myState, setMyState ] = useState()

    //....whatever codes u doing with ur hook.

    const exampleCustomFunction = () => {
          return myState
    }
    const getAllRoutes = async (mydestination) => {
         return await getAllMyRoutesFromApi(mydestination)
     }
      
    // you return all your "getter" and "setter" in value props so you can use them outside the store.
    return <MyStoreContext.Provider value={{ myState, setMyState, exampleCustomFunction, getAllRoutes }}>{props.children}</MyStoreContext.Provider>
}
```

You will wrap the store around your entire App, e.g.

```
<MyStoreProvider>
    <App />
</MyStoreProvider>
```

In your page where you want to use your hook, you can do

```
const { myState, setMyState, exampleCustomFunction, getAllRoutes } = useMyStore()

const onClick = async () => getAllRouters(mydestination)
```

Considering if you have client side routing (not server side), this doesn't get reloaded every time you change your route.