# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component for setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I get a warning
" Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component "
when i am running this code

```
function timer() {

    const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date());
    useEffect(() => {
            setInterval(() => setDateState(new Date()), 1000);
    }, []);

    return(
        <div className="container">
        <p className="text-end text-danger">{dateState.toLocaleDateString('fr-BE' , {
                day : 'numeric',
                month : 'short',
                year: 'numeric'
            })}</p>
        <div className="text-center">
            <h3 className="text-info">
                {dateState.toLocaleString('fr-BE', {
                    hour: 'numeric',
                    minute: 'numeric',
                    second : 'numeric',
                    hour24: true,
                })}
            </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default timer;
```

I tried to do

```
    const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date());
    useEffect(() => {
        let mount = true;
        if(mount){
            setInterval(() => setDateState(new Date()), 1000);
        }
        return () => { isMounted = false };
    }, []);
```

But still not working, i'm kind of stuck...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useEffect - Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59524063/useeffect-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cleanup the setInterval timer on component unmount, like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => setDateState(new Date()), 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, []);
```