# React Router 6 and useEffect cleanup

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, use-effect

After upgrading to React Router 6, React returns this error in any component where I fetch data from an API:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

1. What can I do about this error?
2. What about React Router 6 introduced the issue?

The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-without-cleanup) say "Network requests...don't require a cleanup." Isn't this `useEffect` example a network request, therefore able to ignore cleanup?

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const token = await getAccessTokenSilently()
      const config = {
        url: '/api/rules/dashboard',
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
      try {
        const { data } = await axios(config)
        setData(data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response.data)
        console.log(error.response.status)
      } finally {
        setLoading(false)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently])
```

Comment: it is the warning thrown by react when you try to set the state of component which is no more mounted. It has nothing to do with your api calls.
I think you have setup private routes and or any route with authentication conditions.

Comment: You should be able to sort this out by adding a flag to check if the component is unmounted before using `setData` or `setLoading` after your axios request. Here is a previous answer that should sort out your problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59524322/4364635

Comment: what is happening inside `getAccessTokenSilently()`? are you unmounting the component by pushing to the history?

Comment: @MWO `getAccessTokenSilently` is part of a hook [provided by Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-react#call-an-api). It provides a token to authenticate against an API. I'm not sure if it requires an unmount.

Comment: @jacobSmit the check for an unmounted component appears to use an arbitrary boolean variable called `unmounted`. If I add an unnamed function that resets the state, the error goes away.    `return function cleanup() { setData([]) }`

Comment: @MWO how does one write a dummy token, and what is the goal of doing so?